# fontspec, defining boldfont using diskfiles directly not possible?

Tags: fontspec

I'm defining my mainfont using fontspec, providing an additional option for the italic fontshape:

```
\setmainfont[Path=C:/fonts/SabonNext/, ItalicFont = SabonNextLT-ItalicOsF.otf]{SabonNextLT-RegularOsF.otf} % Sabon next
```

It works perfectly, with the italic shape being the right one

However as soon as i try to define the BoldFont I run into troubles, and get the font-not-found error. I tried changing the filename to something simple and it didnt work, I tried the same for other fonts and got the same problem, defining italic font works perfectly, but boldfont is not possible to define:

preamble:

```
\setmainfont[Path=C:/fonts/SabonNext/, ItalicFont = SabonNextLT-ItalicOsF.otf, BoldFont = SabonNextLT-DemiOsF.otf]{SabonNextLT-RegularOsF.otf} % Sabon next
```

part of my log:

```
\g_fontspec_family_SabonNextLT-RegularOsF.otf_int=\count318
     fontspec info: Defining font family 'SabonNextLT-RegularOsF.otf(0)' for font '
    SabonNextLT-RegularOsF.otf' with options [Path=C:/fonts/SabonNext/, ItalicFont 
    = SabonNextLT-ItalicOsF.otf, BoldFont = SabonNextLT-DemiOsF.otf].


\g_fontspec_SabonNextLT-RegularOsF.otf(0)_prop=\toks58
 fontspec info: Defining shape 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)  <->"[C:/fonts/SabonNext/SabonNextLT-RegularOsF.otf]/ICU:script=latn
;language=DFLT;"

 fontspec info: Defining shape 'bold' with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)  <->"[C:/fonts/SabonNext/SabonNextLT-DemiOsF.otf]/ICU:script=latn;la
nguage=DFLT;"

 fontspec info: Defining shape 'italic' with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)  <->"[C:/fonts/SabonNext/SabonNextLT-ItalicOsF.otf]/ICU:script=latn;
language=DFLT;"



!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
! 
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "SabonNextLT-DemiOsF.otf/I" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.42 ...T-DemiOsF.otf]{SabonNextLT-RegularOsF.otf}
                                                   % Sabon next
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| A font might not be found for many reasons.
| Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.
| 
| When in doubt, ask someone for help!
|...............................................
```

Perhaps somebody could try and reproduce the error (with their own installed fonts?)

Comment: It seems that fontspec chokes when trying to define the Bold Italic font. Try specifying one font also for this shape.

Comment: so you were able to reproduce the problem? ofcourse I can define the fonts in a different way, as i'm doing now. But it seems a bug in fontspec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem with the Linux Biolinum fonts:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[BoldFont = fxbb.otf,
             %BoldItalicFont=fxlbi.otf
             ]{fxbr.otf}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

And I don't think it is a bug. The documentation says that it can happen that the bold italic font is not found and that you can provide it with the BoldItalicFont option:

> The BoldFont and ItalicFont features
>   are provided for these situations. If
>   only one of these is used, the bold
>   italic font is requested as the
>   default from the new font. See Example
>   4. If a bold italic shape is not defined, or you want to specify both
>   custom bold and italic shapes, the
>   BoldItalicFont feature is provided.

Comment: it works only if i specify bold, italic and bolditalic fonts... Althought that seems abit strange to me, it's sufficient for now :)

Comment: If you declare only one font, fontspec has a clear starting point and also a clear "fall back" font if it can't find suitable italic and bold variant. But when you use the ItalicFont/BoldFont option two or three fonts are involved. This makes it much more difficult to decide automatically what the user actually wants for the last combination and so I think it is better if fontspec asks you do to specify the bolditalic too.

Comment: ok, that makes more sense to me. But still it's strange that I get an ordinary font not found error, and it even suggest changing fontname etc.